# Trying to run a simple Java ActionListener example and getting an error?

Tags: java, actionlistener

I have this code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*; 
import java.awt.*;
public class Stu {


public static void main(String[] args){
    int dl = 3000;
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        System.out.print("do");//do a task
    }

};

}

}
```

And it gives me this error:

```
Stu.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
```

I need help understanding how that works. Does ActionListener need a GUI to run? thanks

Comment: You have not imported `ActionListener`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - OK I will do this. thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ActionListener` interface is in `java.awt.event`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html); import it (same for `ActionEvent`).

But even if you do, your code won't do anything.  Nothing is calling your `actionPerformed` method.  Implementing `ActionListener` makes sense only if you add your `ActionListener` to some other object that produces `ActionEvent`s that you want to react to, and that means creating a GUI, because other GUI classes support this mechanism.

Comment: Thanks so much! You're right, I ran it but it doesn't do anything. Ok I will look into that further. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

As Sotirios said, I need to import ActionListener(also , ActionEvent) .

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
public class Stu {


public static void main(String[] args){
     /* same as before */
}
}
```